# Can Visual Studio open and close files on one click (One click open and close)

Tags: visual-studio, xcode

Im an xcode developer and the one thing I love about xcode and am missing when im coding c# in visual studio is the feature to open and close files upon one click.

Is it possible to set up visual studio to behave like xcode in this fashion?

Comment: select the single click open from folder-option

Comment: I'd love this feature! I do not understand moon's answer. You can press F7 after selecting a file to open it but I doubt this is any more convenient.

Comment: VS 11 (currently in beta but usable) has the ability to open a file with a single click.

Comment: The open file with single click feature was officially released in the Visual Studio 2012 RTM.

Comment: The feature is "Preview Selected Items", and is available (at least) as a button at the top of the Solution Explorer panel.  Note that the feature closes the file again once you deselect it.